# How do I specify a specific file in Google Cloud Storage to trigger a Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to monitor a specific file in my Google Cloud Storage bucket and just trigger my Cloud Function when that file is modified.

When using the Cloud Function web UI, I select the trigger type of:

"On (metadata update) of the file in the selected bucket"

However, nowhere do I see how to specify "the file".

I have tried using the bucket browse UI and it only allows selecting a bucket, not a specific file in a bucket.

I have also reviewed the documentation for Cloud Storage triggers and it seems to treat the metadata update trigger just like the other 3 available triggers, which do not have "the file" in their descriptions.

I am starting to think it is just a typo in the web UI and there is no "the file" to specify, it just "a file" like the other triggers.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot specify the file in these triggers but only the bucket. This means that all objects will trigger the function so you may need to filter which objects will be processed or not at code level.

Comment: Thank you @Puteri that was my suspicion at this point, even though the label for the trigger is unique among the 4 options and indicated to me at least, it would monitor a specific file. Barring anyone else who knows differently, if you would please make your comment an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file cannot be specified or filtered but only the bucket ([Doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage)). This means that all objects will trigger the function so you may need to filter which objects will be processed or not at code level.

> When you specify a Cloud Storage trigger for a function, you choose an event type and specify a Cloud Storage bucket. Your function will be called whenever a change occurs on an object (file) within the specified bucket.

To avoid high charges on this, the filtering should be the first thing to do to reduce as possible CPU and Memory utilization since the function is terminated as soon as possible.